# gethostbyname() and valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, gethostbyname

I keep getting this error whenever I call gethostbyname() in my C code.

```
==7983== Invalid read of size 1
==7983==    at 0x412AB2C: ____strtoul_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
==7983==    by 0x412A46F: strtoul (strtol.c:110)
==7983==    by 0x41D427E: inet_aton (inet_addr.c:143)
==7983==    by 0x41D8FF3: __nss_hostname_digits_dots (digits_dots.c:144)
==7983==    by 0x41DD0F9: gethostbyname (getXXbyYY.c:109)
==7983==    by 0x804BE6F: connexion_function (in  ***************)
==7983==    by 0x8049A8F: main (in ***************)
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks,

Comment: What arguments do you give to gethostbyname and how do you initialize them?

Comment: thanks ypnos, i'll just use getaddrinfo() instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to the fact that `gethostbyname` is non-reentrant and returns an object that is shared by all threads. You should probably use [getaddrinfo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html) and [freeaddrinfo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html) in lieu of [gethostbyname](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html).